# Comm, awk alternative for php

Tags: php, comm

I have 2 files:
**images1.txt**
--file1
--file2
--file5
--file6
--file7
**images2.txt**
--file1
--file5
--file6

I need to be created file images_to_delete.txt with expected result:
**images_to_delete.txt**
--file2
--file7

I know i could do this with bash using command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' images2.txt images1.txt > images_to_delete.txt
```

Is there any possibility to do this in PHP without using shell_exec?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using these :

read files into an array
[file function](http://fr.php.net/file)

get difference between two arrays
[array_diff function](http://fr.php.net/array_diff)